# Keep data in offline app React Native

Tags: react-native, offline

I want to create offline an alphabet app for children using React-Native, and I want to ask you what is the best way to store data about each letter, for example: letter ID, letter NAME, letter IMG_SRC etc. I thought about using JSON, but as well decided to ask you about it. May be there's a better way. I'll be very happy if you share your own experience with me)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to store offline data is using the [AsyncStorage](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html), it's basically a key value storage, super easy to use. You can save json in there or any other text, for example:

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('data', JSON.stringify([{id: 1, name: 'a', src: ''}]));
```

Then, later on, you can get that data like this:

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('data', (err, result) => {
  console.log(JSON.parse(result));
});
```

For simple apps, this is more than enough