# React native Array/Json downloading

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs, file, react-native

I have react native app, then working with such structure:
in main.js I have

```
import newspapers from './newspapers.js';
```

In newspapers.js I have now :

```
let papersList = [
{id:1, imageName: '2.jpg', paperName: '02 jan 2019', pdfName: '2.pdf', downloaded:false, downloading:false},
{id:2, imageName: '3.jpg', paperName: '27 dec2018', pdfName: '3.pdf', downloaded:false, downloading:false},
]     
export default papersList
```

So it's array with what I work, and it works now.
But I need to download this list from server and store it somewhere when app in offline mode. I came up with this solution like:

```
import RNFetchBlob from 'rn-fetch-blob';
RNFetchBlob
.config({
    path : RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/'+ 'index.json'
})
.fetch('GET', 'https://mysite/App/index.json', {
})
.then((res) => {
    console.log('The file saved to ', res.path())
})

RNFetchBlob.fs.readFile(RNFetchBlob.fs.dirs.DocumentDir + '/'+ 'index.json', 'utf8')
.then((data) => {
    let papersList = JSON.parse(data)
})
export default papersList
```

But it's not working at all. How can I download smth, and then export it like json array? Or smth like that? 
Many using componentDidMount? But I dont understand how should I do it.
I would be very grateful for any help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48571223/keep-data-in-offline-app-react-native